# Display minimum value excluding zero along with adjacent column value from each year + Python 3+, dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy, dataframe, minimum

I have a dataframe with three columns as Year, Product, Price. I wanted to calculate minimum value excluding zero from Price from each year. Also wanted to populate adjacent value from column Product to the minimum value.

Data:

```
Year  Product       Price
2000   Grapes       0
2000   Apple        220
2000   pear         185
2000   Watermelon   172
2001   Orange       0 
2001   Muskmelon    90
2001   Pear         165
2001   Watermelon   99
```

Desirable output in new dataframe:

```
Year  Minimum Price  Product
2000  172            Watermelon  
2001  90             Muskmelon
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First filter out `0` rows by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df1 = df[df['Price'] != 0]
```

And then use [`DataFrameGroupBy.idxmin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.idxmin.html) for indices for minimal `Price` per groups with selecting by [`loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```
df2 = df1.loc[df1.groupby('Year')['Price'].idxmin()]
```

Alternative is use [`sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) with [`drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html):

```
df2 = df1.sort_values(['Year', 'Price']).drop_duplicates('Year')

print (df2)
   Year     Product  Price
3  2000  Watermelon    172
5  2001   Muskmelon     90
```

If possible multiple minimal values and need all of them per groups:

```
print (df)
   Year     Product  Price
0  2000      Grapes      0
1  2000       Apple    220
2  2000        pear    172
3  2000  Watermelon    172
4  2001      Orange      0
5  2001   Muskmelon     90
6  2001        Pear    165
7  2001  Watermelon     99

df1 = df[df['Price'] != 0]
df = df1[df1['Price'].eq(df1.groupby('Year')['Price'].transform('min'))]
print (df)
   Year     Product  Price
2  2000        pear    172
3  2000  Watermelon    172
5  2001   Muskmelon     90
```

EDIT:

```
print (df)
   Year     Product  Price
0  2000      Grapes      0
1  2000       Apple    220
2  2000        pear    185
3  2000  Watermelon    172
4  2001      Orange      0
5  2001   Muskmelon     90
6  2002        Pear      0
7  2002  Watermelon      0

df['Price'] = df['Price'].replace(0, np.nan)
df2 = df.sort_values(['Year', 'Price']).drop_duplicates('Year')
df2['Product'] = df2['Product'].mask(df2['Price'].isnull(), 'No data')
print (df2)
   Year     Product  Price
3  2000  Watermelon  172.0
5  2001   Muskmelon   90.0
6  2002     No data    NaN
```

Comment: Can we exclude zero without creating new dataframe for the same to calculate minimum?

Comment: @sourabhnigam - yes, it is possible by `df2 = df.loc[df.groupby('Year')['Price'].apply(lambda x: x[(x != 0)].idxmin())]`, but it is slowier

Comment: Thanks, I am getting an error as "ValueError: attempt to get argmin of an empty sequence". Can it display a message "No data" in case of non availability of non zero values in a particular year?

Comment: @sourabh - give me a sec.

Comment: @sourabh - not so easy, I add `No data` string to `product` column. Is possible add it also to `Price`, but get numeric data with strings, so it is not recommended. But possible by add code to end of my solution - `df2['Price'] = df2['Price'].fillna('No data')`